# Add or remove specific jars from custom ClassLoader

Tags: java, jar, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I want to create [dynamically a classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864832/create-classloader-with-only-classes-inside-specific-folder) for executing JSR223 script in a controlled environment but failing,

I'm trying remove/add jars using current(parent) ClassLoader, I tried solution [Dynamically removing jars from classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350118/dynamically-removing-jars-from-classpath)

> ```
> public class DistributionClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
>     public DistributionClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
>         super(parent);
>     }
>     private Map<String, ClassLoader> classLoadersByDistribution =
>             Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<>());
>     private final AtomicReference<String> distribution = new AtomicReference<>();
>     @Override
>     protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
>     throws ClassNotFoundException {
>         final ClassLoader delegate = classLoadersByDistribution.get(distribution.get());
>         if (delegate != null) return Class.forName(name, true, delegate);
>         throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
>     }
>     public void addDistribution(String key, ClassLoader distributionClassLoader){
>         classLoadersByDistribution.put(key,distributionClassLoader);
>     }
>     public void makeDistributionActive(String key){distribution.set(key);}
>     public void removeDistribution(String key){
>         final ClassLoader toRemove = classLoadersByDistribution.remove(key);
>     }
> }
> ```

But it didn't include all my jars, in test this work

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
Class cls = cl.loadClass("org.springframework.http.HttpStatus");
```

But using the solution doesn't find class

```
ClassLoader cl = new DistributionClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class cls = cl.loadClass("org.springframework.http.HttpStatus");
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
    at com.DistributionClassLoader.loadClass(DistributionClassLoader.java:24)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

How can I select **specific** jars to add or remove from ClassLoader?

**EDIT**

I'm able to load jars using [@czdepski answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime/52616924#52616924) but I still want to remove all/most classes except JDK's

> ```
> Method sysMethod = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
> sysMethod.setAccessible(true);
> sysMethod.invoke(sysLoader, new Object[]{url});
> ```

Comment: Can you explain why exactly you want to remove stuff from class loader? as it's not exactly possible, you can't force-unload class. Classes might be garbage collected with a class loader. Please provide some examples where you need something like that.

Comment: @gotofinal see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63538

Comment: I don't see how is this related to removing jars from class loader, when executing a groovy script just need to load it using different class loader that does not use that library. So such libraries should not be part of parent class loader. As removing them from parent class loader will not change anything anyway.

Comment: @gotofinal how do you create classloader on basis of existing classloader?

Comment: check if what I wrote in the answer does anything similar to what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the delegation wrong. You never check the parent class loader if it has this class.

If we look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String,boolean)) for `ClassLoader.loadClass(String,boolean)` we find:

> Loads the class with the specified binary name. The default implementation of this method searches for classes in the following order:
>
> 1. Invoke `findLoadedClass(String)` to check if the class has already been loaded.
> 2. Invoke the `loadClass` method on the parent class loader. If the parent is null the class loader built into the virtual machine is used, instead.
> 3. Invoke the `findClass(String)` method to find the class.
>
> If the class was found using the above steps, and the resolve flag is true, this method will then invoke the resolveClass(Class) method on the resulting Class object.
>
> **Subclasses of ClassLoader are encouraged to override findClass(String), rather than this method.**

You did override `loadClass`, but don't do any delegation to it's parent ClassLoader.
Instead you call `classLoadersByDistribution.get(distribution.get());`, which is most likely `null` (hard to tell, but always expect `WeakHashMap.get()` to return `null`).

If `delegate` is not null, then you try to load the class from there. This means the loaded class won't use your ClassLoader to load new classes, but instead the ClassLoader you delegated to.

After all, this sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/190161). You want to execute some code using the scripting API and somehow control the environment.
Did you try to use a `SecurityManager`?

---

About your comment that you need your own `ClassLoader` to create a [ScriptEngineManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html#ScriptEngineManager(java.lang.ClassLoader)): This ClassLoader is used to search for  ScriptEngineFactory implementations. This is done using a [service provider interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)).
If you don't use your own script engine, this should not matter to you.

---

If your goal is to add a few jars so the engine can use it, create a new `URLClassLoader` with the platform class loader as parent. (Or extension class loader, depends on the java version.)
Set this ClassLoader as `Thread.setContextClassLoader()` and create the ScriptEngine.

If you did choose the parent of the `URLClassLoader` correctly, it will not see classes loadable by the application class loader.

Comment: About last commet, I need ClassLoader, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html#ScriptEngineManager(java.lang.ClassLoader)

Comment: So you want to provide your own ScriptEngine? Loaded through your own ClassLoader?

Comment: I want to update(add/remove jars) using current classloader before sending to ScriptEngine

Comment: You should not modify a ClassLoader after it's creation. It's dangerous. (See the JVMS about loading classes.)

Comment: but I want to use a more secure/configrable classloader on a basis of existing classloader

Comment: More secure than `URLClassLoader`? Good luck with that. No really, what do you want?

Comment: Yeah, see my last paragraph. Don't implement your own ClassLoader. It's tricky to do, so just use an `URLClassLoader` as context class loader when creating the engine.

Comment: But then I failed to add jars, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864832/create-classloader-with-only-classes-inside-specific-folder?r=SearchResults

Comment: Use the right parent when creating the URLClassLoader. On java 7 that might mean using `null` as parent. Which might exclude classes loaded via extension class loader.